# How can I populate a field dependent on the values from four other fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a field, `RoadmapType`, which is populated with a hardcoded string based on the combination of values from four other fields, `InvestmentCategory`, `FundingClass`, `InvestmentClass` & `Lifecycle`. The value determining RoadmapType can vary, for example, in one instance, to get the RoadmapType "Incremental", the value of `InvestmentCategory` can be either "Enterprise" or "IT Roadmap", and the value of `InvestmentClass` can be "Transform", "Scale", "NPI" or "Run".

Right now, I am doing this the long way, where I am using multiple `if` blocks for each potential `RoadmapType`.  I want a shorter, more reliable method to get my desired out come.

This table shows 3 example combinations and the resulting `RoadmapType`.  *Please note that only one value from each column can be used at a time*.

| Investment Category | Funding Class | Investment Class | Lifecycle | *Roadmap Type* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Enterprise Roadmap, IT Roadmap | Incremental | Transform, Scale, NPI, Run | Any value | *Incremental* |
| Enterprise Roadmap | Roadmap | Transform, NPI | All except DD | *Roadmap - BAT* |
| Enterprise Roadmap | Chargeback | Transform, Scale, NPI, Run | IPT, SDM | *Chargeback - DTS* |

These are the `if` blocks I am using to get a `RoadmapType`of "Compliance".

```
const onTextChange = (e) => {
    var id = e.target.id ? e?.target.id : e?.target.name;
    var value = e.target.value;
    function setRoadmapType(fieldId, fieldVal, roadmapTypeVal) {
        setDetails({ ...details, [fieldId]: fieldVal, RoadmapType: roadmapTypeVal });
    }
    if (
        id === "InvestmentClass" &&
        value === "Compliance" &&
        details?.FundingClass === "Roadmap" &&
        details?.InvestmentCategory === "Enterprise Roadmap"
    ) {
        setRoadmapType(id, value, "Roadmap - Compliance");
    } else if (
        id === "FundingClass" &&
        value === "Roadmap" &&
        details?.InvestmentClass === "Compliance" &&
        details?.InvestmentCategory === "Enterprise Roadmap"
    ) {
        setRoadmapType(id, value, "Roadmap - Compliance");
    } else if (
        // ! NOT WORKING when investment category is input as the deciding value of RoadmapType
        id === "InvestmentCategory" &&
        value === "Enterprise Roadmap" &&
        details?.InvestmentClass === "Compliance" &&
        details?.FundingClass === "Roadmap"
    ) else {
        setDetails({ ...details, [id]: value });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by extracting the calculation logic into a [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This design pattern isolates the algorithm, independently from clients that may use it.

```
const onTextChange = (e) => {
    var id = e.target.id ? e?.target.id : e?.target.name;
    var value = e.target.value;
    function setRoadmapType(fieldId, fieldVal, roadmapTypeVal) {
        setDetails({ ...details, [fieldId]: fieldVal, RoadmapType: roadmapTypeVal });
    }
    let computedValue = RoadmapTypeStrategy.computeType(id, value, details);
    setRoadmapType(id, value, computedValue);
}


//First version of RoadmapTypeStrategy.js - computational logic extracted into a Strategy
const computeType = (id, value, details) => {
if (
    id === "InvestmentClass" &&
    value === "Compliance" &&
    details?.FundingClass === "Roadmap" &&
    details?.InvestmentCategory === "Enterprise Roadmap"
) {
    return "Roadmap - Compliance";
} else if (
    id === "FundingClass" &&
    value === "Roadmap" &&
    details?.InvestmentClass === "Compliance" &&
    details?.InvestmentCategory === "Enterprise Roadmap"
) {
    return "Roadmap - Compliance";
} else if (
    id === "InvestmentCategory" &&
    value === "Enterprise Roadmap" &&
    details?.InvestmentClass === "Compliance" &&
    details?.FundingClass === "Roadmap"
) else {
    return "default";
}
};
const RoadmapTypeStrategy = {
    computeType
};
export default RoadmapTypeStrategy;
```

Then, IF the total number of combinations is not too large, the best way I can think of to avoid all those if statements is by creating a class with 4 fields containing the possible combination values, and 1 field for the value. You can then compare them and fetch the value if the objects match. The downside is you need to create 1 instance of the Combination class per possible values combination.

```
//Final version of RoadmapTypeStrategy.js - adds more concise conditions tests via an array of objects
class Combination {
    constructor(investmentCategory, fundingClass, investmentClass, lifecycle, value) {
        this.investmentCategory = investmentCategory;
        this.fundingClass = fundingClass;
        this.investmentClass = investmentClass;
        this.lifecycle = lifecycle;
        this.value = value;
    }
    matches(invCat, funClass, invClass, lifecycle) {
        return (this.investmentCategory === invCat && this.fundingClass === funClass && this.investmentClass === invClass && this.lifecycle === lifecycle);
    }
}

const combinations = [
    new Combination('Enterprise Roadmap', 'Incremental', 'Transform', 'IPT', 'Incremental'),
    new Combination('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
    new Combination(/* etc */)
];

const matches = (combination, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) => {
    return combination.matches(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
};

const computeType = (id, value, details) => {
    return (combinations.some((c) => matches(c, id, value, details?.FundingClass, details?.InvestmentCategory)) ) ?
        combinations.find((c) => matches(c, id, value, details?.FundingClass, details?.InvestmentCategory)).value :
    'default value';
};
const RoadmapTypeStrategy = {
    computeType
};
export default RoadmapTypeStrategy;
```

Let me know if this helps, and is clear enough.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a working example of RoadmapStrategy.js?  I am getting all sorts of errors on `const computeType`.  I am also unsure as to how values would be passed into RoadmapStrategy

Comment: How does this code determine the RoadmapType?  For example, if I want a RoadmapType  of `Roadmap - BAT`, my options are as follows: `InvestmentCategory-Enterprise Roadmap`, `FundingClass-Roadmap`, `InvestmentClass-Transform, NPI`, `Lifecycle-All values except DD`.  What would a `Combination` which results in Roadmap - BAT look like?

Comment: For the first values (all except lifecycle), it would be as simple as adding "new Combination(InvestmentCategory-Enterprise Roadmap, FundingClass-Roadmap, InvestmentClass-Transform, NPI)" to the list of combinations. Indeed, for the "blacklist" value for lifecycle, my current code would need to go further.

Comment: Thanks.  Then how does a combination get matched to a RoadmapType?  Does this happen in computeType?  How would a Combination like the one in my previous comment get matched to its corresponding RoadmapType?  I can see that in your code, you are passing `Incremental` as the last value of the combination.  Does this code take the first 4 values and look for the combination which contains them?  Some combinations allow for any Lifecycle value to be input.  Does this mean that i would need a new combination for each Lifecycle, even though it results in the same RoadmapType?

Comment: The constructor of the Combination class accepts 5 arguments: Investment Category, Funding Class, Investment Class, Lifecycle, Roadmap Type. Each created Combination takes the values for those fields you specified in the table. When computeType() is called, the code simply checks to see if a Combination exists for the provided IC, FC, IC, L arguments (using "some" and "find" operators). If so, it returns that Combination's Roadmap type; otherwise a default value. In the current state it means you need a new Combination for each lifecycle (barring the question of white/black listing values)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246951/discussion-between-ciaran-crowley-and-chris-neve).